# Javascript TagName

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to get a TagName that is below a TagName.

For example:

```
<strong><em>Test</em></strong>
<em>Test2</em>
```

Is it possible to only get the  tag in the  tag?  In other words, only the Test elements should be returned.

The most I can figure out is `var x = document.getElementsByTagName("strong")`
and I want something along the lines of `x = x.getElementsByTagName("em")`.  (I have practically no js experience)

Limitations: I am using Confluence so I am unable to to change the html i.e. no ID's/classes for these elements.

Comment: So what's the problem with `document.getElementsByTagName("em")`?

Comment: Or `var x = document.querySelectorAll('strong em')`

Comment: If there is only 1 element then then `var x = document.querySelector('strong em')`

Comment: @Bartek Banachewicz: I only want the strong em.  Thanks. Arun P Johny, I'll try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PURE JS SOLOUTION**

You will probably need to parse more than one tag. For this situation you can use something like this.

```
//get all "em" elements
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("em");
//prepare final array
var tags = [];

//go throught every "em" element
for(var index in elements) { 
   if (elements.hasOwnProperty(index)) {
       //check if element parent is <STRONG>
       if(elements[index].parentNode.nodeName == 'STRONG'){
        tags.push(elements[index].innerHTML)
       }
   }
}

//final array with tags
console.log(tags);
```

This will return all tags from string with pattern `<strong><em>Tag</em></strong>`

For example, if you have this HTML

```
<strong><em>Test</em></strong>
<em>Test2</em><strong><em>Test2</em></strong>
<em>Test2</em><strong><em>Test3</em></strong>
<em>Test2</em><strong><em>Test4</em></strong>
<em>Test2</em><strong><em>Test5</em></strong>
<em>Test2</em><strong><em>Test6</em></strong>
<em>Test2</em><strong><em>Test7</em></strong>
<em>Test2</em><strong><em>Test8</em></strong>
<em>Test2</em><strong><em>Test9</em></strong>
<em>Test2</em><strong><em>Test10</em></strong>
```

Output will be:

```
["Test", "Test2", "Test3", "Test4", "Test5", "Test6", "Test7", "Test8", "Test9", "Test10"]
```

Comment: You...are...legend!  I am sure you're psychic.  That is not exactly my problem but it sure will solve it.  This was the next step I was working on.  Trying to add ids to <strong id = "id"><em> and where there is no strong tag, <em id = "id2">.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use vanilla JS, you can use something like this:

`document.querySelectorAll('strong em')`

You can get more information about CSS selectors [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors).

Comment: Thanks, this is what I will go use, saves all the looping.  Thanks, didn't know about selectors.

Comment: This should be done with plain js, there is no need to use external js library for this...

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByTagName("strong")` will return you a collection of items, so to call it again, you need to actually call it on an item of that collection, like `x[0].getElementsByTagName("em")`. So you'll need to loop all the elements of `x` and execute on each of them `getElementsByTagName` and collect all the children in an array.

Comment: Yeah thats the solution I just came to, feel stupid for asking now.

Comment: Don't worry - everyone of us at some point asks something obvious ;)

Comment: Loops are unnecessary here.

Answer (score 0):

since `document.getElementsByTagName` will give array what you need is index `0`

```js
console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("em")[0].innerHTML);
```

```html
<strong><em>Test</em></strong>
<em>Test2</em>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('strong em');
console.log(elements);
```

This will return only ems which are under strong tag

You could use also class selectors too like:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('strong em.myclass');
```

Comment: Read the OP please. "Limitations: I am using Confluence so I am unable to to change the html i.e. no ID's/classes for these elements."

Comment: This is literally the jcollado's answer

Comment: @ Gökay - I gave the answer of the particular question, and then just clarify that *it's possible* to use it with any other selector. I've wrote this because the OP express the concerns that he has no big js experience.

Answer (score -1):

You could use query selector like this:

If you use jQuery

```
$("strong em");
```

Otherwise:

```
document.querySelectorAll("strong em");
```

Comment: OP doesn't mention anything about jQuery.

Comment: OP also said he has practically no experience in JavaScript. I think the down votes are a bit harsh. It could have been worded better, like queryselectorall only works in HTML5 odd browsers IE9+, jQuery is a good tool to consider.